# C++: can an int be assigned a char*?

Tags: c++, linux, casting, char

I am reading chapter 2 of Advanced Linux Programming:
http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch02-writing-good-gnu-linux-software.pdf

In the section `2.1.3 Using getopt_long`, there is an example program that goes a bit like this:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int next_option;
  // ...
  do {
    next_option = getopt_long (argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
    switch (next_option) {
       case ‘h’: /* -h or --help */
       // ...
    }
    // ...
```

The bit that caught my attention is that next_option is declared as an int. The function getopt_long() apparently returns an int representing the short command line argument which is used in the following switch statement. How come that integer can be compared to a character in the switch statement?

Is there an implicit conversion from a char (a single character?) to an int? How is the code above valid? (see full code in linked pdf)

Comment: Um... First, you say that "getopt_long() apparently returns a char*". Then you ask "Is there an implicit casting from a char to an int". The first part is about `char *`, the second is about `char`. Where is the connection?

Comment: @AndreyT : did you look at the code I'm trying to understand? next_option is declared as an int but is compared to a character in the switch statment. Check the source code in the pdf.

Comment: There's no point to continue, since you have already edited the question to remove the `char *`-related part.

Comment: @AndreyT  I am still trying to understand the code in the book. I'm still confused and would like to understand why the code is valid.

Comment: I already provided you with a rather exhaustive explanation below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ have a type that can store "characters" as values with some dedicated character-specific properties. In that sense, there's no "character" type neither in C nor in C++.

In both C++ and C languages `char` is an *integral* type. It contains *numbers*. It is just a smallest (in terms of range) integral type. Conversion between `char` and `int` exists, just like it exists between `int` and `long` or `int` and `short`. `char` has no special status among other integral types (aside from the fact that `char` type it is distinct from `signed char` type).

A literal of the form `'h'` in C++ has type `char`, but as any other integral type it is comparable to `int`. That's why you can use it in `case` label the way it is used in your original example.

In other words, your original code is as "strange" as

```
switch (next_option) {
       case 1L: ...
       // ...
    }
```

would be. In this case the `switch` argument is an `int`, but the case label is a `long`. The code is valid. Do you find it surprising? Probably not. Your example with `'h'` is in not much different.

Comment: I really wish the tag "newbie" were accepted here. Yes, I do find things like this surprising. I didn't expect it. You provided some pointers to concepts I could search and study more. I'll need time for this to sink in. Thanks.

Comment: "char has no special status among other integral types" It has no trap values! :)

Comment: @GMan i regard that as a little useful property, though :( You can still not reliable use it to copy over arbitrary bytes, because only for *unsigned char*, it's guaranteed that the copied bytes are exactly the same (for `char`, you may have multiple representations for the same value, for instance a "negative" and "positive" 0).

Answer (score 4):

You are mistaken -- [`getopt_long(3)`](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring04/cps108/resources/getoptman.html) returns an int.

Comment: So how come this int can be compared to 'h' or other characters in the switch statement?

Comment: Thanks for the notice but it does not answer my question. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: a char is nothing particularly special, just a 1-byte integer-type variable. If you compare a char to an int, it's as if you're comparing two ints (same as int to long or long long).

Comment: @jkerian Thanks. You answer more or less what I was really trying to ask. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Several functions return `int` in C, but `char` in C++.  Returning an `int` when a `char` would make more sense is simply an old C cultural decision.  Plus, in a few cases, it's necessary so that a function can return sentinels like `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answerer says, you're asking the wrong question here. But to answer the question you *did* ask:

No implicit casting from char* to an int is available. On x86 machines, both int and char* are 32 bits long, so it's "safe" to explicitly cast:

```
int x = (int*) &someChar;
```

BUT HIGHLY NOT RECOMMENDED!!!

On x64 machines, *this will not work*! int remains 32 bits long, but all pointers are now 64 bits long... so you'll lose data in the process!

Comment: So, what do you make of the sample code in chapter 2 of "Advanced Linux Programming"? How should the code be re-factored to be safe on my 64 bit CPU/OS?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page, getopt_long returns an `int`. And yes, there is an implicit cast from `char` to `int`; a `char` is just a one-byte integer value.

So in this case, the cast is not happening when assigning to `next_option`, but in the `case` statement where you have a character constant being compared to an `int`. Of course, this is assuming you compile this as C++. In C++, a character constant is of type `char`, but in C it's of type `int`, so if you compile this code as C then there's no type conversion at all.

(And in your question you mention `char*`, but you probably meant `char`; there are no pointers being used here.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of a char as a 8bit int. You can perform integer operations on chars and you can even declare them as unsigned. You wouldn't be surprised if you could compare a short and a long. Why should comparing a char and an int be different?

Comment: No, don't think of it as an 8 bit int. Think of it as the smallest integral type in C++, which may or may not be 8 bits and may or may not be signed or unsigned.

Comment: In C++ a byte must be at least 8 bits. A char must be a single byte.

Comment: A char is a single byte, and yes it must be at least 8 bits. You said think of it *as* 8 bits, a bad practice to get in to.